# phpunit code coverage does not work in Symfony2 when is passed as parameter

Tags: symfony, phpunit

When using code-coverage my tests are terribly slow, so I want to generate code coverage only when I pass the `--coverage-html=/tmp` option to command like this:

`phpunit --coverage-html=/tmp -c app/`

I also tried changing the order of parameters:
`phpunit -c app/ --coverage-html=/tmp`

PHPUnit version is **3.7.28**.

I have xdebug enabled in PHP CLI:
`php -i | grep xdebug`

```
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini,
xdebug
xdebug support => enabled
xdebug.auto_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.cli_color => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_includes => On => On
xdebug.collect_params => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.coverage_enable => On => On
xdebug.default_enable => On => On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.GET => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.POST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value => no value
xdebug.dump_globals => On => On
xdebug.dump_once => On => On
xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off
xdebug.extended_info => On => On
xdebug.file_link_format => no value => no value
xdebug.idekey => no value => no value
xdebug.max_nesting_level => 250 => 250
xdebug.overload_var_dump => On => On
xdebug.profiler_aggregate => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p => cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_autostart => Off => Off
xdebug.remote_connect_back => Off => Off
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time => 3600 => 3600
xdebug.remote_enable => Off => Off
xdebug.remote_handler => dbgp => dbgp
xdebug.remote_host => localhost => localhost
xdebug.remote_log => no value => no value
xdebug.remote_mode => req => req
xdebug.remote_port => 9000 => 9000
xdebug.scream => Off => Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_local_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c => trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children => 128 => 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data => 512 => 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth => 3 => 3
```

I use the default Symfony2 phpunit.xml.dist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- http://phpunit.de/manual/4.1/en/appendixes.configuration.html -->
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/4.1/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         colors="true"
         bootstrap="bootstrap.php.cache"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
            <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <!--
    <php>
        <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="/path/to/your/app/" />
    </php>
    -->

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory>../src</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

When I use `phpunit --coverage-text -c app` it outputs the results.

It only works when I add logging configuration in `phpunit.xml.dist`:

```
<logging>
    <log type="coverage-html" target="/tmp/report" charset="UTF-8"
         highlight="false" lowUpperBound="35" highLowerBound="70"/>
</logging>
```

When I do that, it always generates the code coverage report, which I don't want to because tests are slow.

Comment: This works for me. Are you sure you're looking for a report in the right directory? ;)

Comment: @JakubZalas I am sure. It doesn't display the `Generating HTML coverage report` message at all. What's your PHPUnit version? Did you install PHPUnit via PEAR or composer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with PHPUnit version 4.0.17 and it works!

I don't know if it matters, but PHPUnit is now installed via PEAR.

`$ phpunit -c app --coverage-html=/tmp`

```
PHPUnit 4.0.17 by Sebastian Bergmann.

You have installed PHPUnit via PEAR. This installation method is no longer
supported and http://pear.phpunit.de/ will be shut down no later than
December, 31 2014.

Please read http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html and
learn how to use PHPUnit from a PHAR or install it via Composer.

Configuration read from /home/usersetup/public_html/project/app/phpunit.xml.dist

..........................................

Time: 3.52 minutes, Memory: 45.00Mb

OK (42 tests, 121 assertions)

Generating code coverage report in HTML format ... done
```

**Update**

I also tried with PHPUnit 4.2.6 installed via composer and it works as well.